# How to prevent `magit-visit-thing` to open an `evil-mode` buffer

Tags: emacs, evil-mode, magit

`evil-mode` has `evil-emacs-state-modes` var, which defines modes to open in `emacs` mode.

I have `magit-diff-mode` listed in that var (in fact, it is a default).

Running `magit-diff` opens correctly in `emacs` mode.

However, if I a run `magit-status` (opens in `emacs mode`), place the point on `Head` (first line in the buffer) and hit <kbd>Ret</kbd>, `magit-visit-thing` is called and and the commit info is shown in a new buffer. This buffer is in `magit-diff-mode`, however, `evil-mode` is active for this buffer.

How do I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure it's in `magit-diff-mode`? Because I've checked and it's in `magit-revision-mode`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. How do you look for the current mode name? I usually hit C-h-m, and this is what it gave me: Magit Rev mode defined in `magit-diff.el'

Comment: Please make turn your comment to answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we figured out in the comments - the buffer opens in `magit-revision-mode`, not in `magit-diff-mode`.

To find out the major mode of the buffer, describe variable `major-mode` - `C-h v major-mode <RET>`.

For you information, when you do `describe-mode` instead (`C-h m`) what you see as mode name is the string that appears in the status line. It may be difficult to guess from it what the actual mode name is - like `Magit Rev` is actually a string for `magit-revision-mode` - no way of knowing unless you look in `magit-diff.el`:

```
define-derived-mode magit-revision-mode magit-diff-mode "Magit Rev"
```